# Ignore empty using IS NOT NULL not working

Tags: php, mysql, null

I've got a query which shows me the most common value in the `TyreMan` column. A lot of the values in this column are empty so I'm trying to ignore them, it doesn't appear to be working though.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT TyreMan, COUNT(TyreMan) AS countTyreMan 
                         FROM Pictures 
                        WHERE Tyreman IS NOT NULL 
                     GROUP BY TyreMan 
                     ORDER BY countTyreMan DESC 
                        LIMIT 1");
```

Have i got it in the wrong place?

thanks

Comment: Are the values empty (means blank) or null?

Comment: Try `WHERE Tyreman IS NOT NULL AND Tyreman <> '' `

Comment: they are empty, i assumed this was null?

Comment: M Khalid Junaid - Perfect, thanks

Comment: Are you on Linux or Windows? On Linux `Tyreman` is not the same as `TyreMan`. From [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html): *"the case sensitivity of the underlying operating system plays a part in the case sensitivity of [...] names."*

Comment: Define "doesn't appear to be working". What _does_ appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT TyreMan, COUNT(TyreMan) AS countTyreMan 
      FROM Pictures WHERE (Tyreman) IS NOT NULL 
      GROUP BY TyreMan ORDER BY countTyreMan DESC LIMIT 1");
```

Use () with column name.

Comment: Why is this needed? It should not be. _Explain_ your answer, please, preferably with evidence.